# Blurriness of logo and icons at different zoom levels

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, top-bar, editor

Starting today (11/27) I noticed the inbox, achievements, review, and site switcher icons are very blurry at 100% zoom in IE11. I cannot reproduce in Chrome 59+. I'm on Windows 7. Surely IE11 support should exist for the sprites?

[image: blurry icons main toolbar]

Some of the icons on the edit toolbar of the post area are blurry as well.

[image: blurry icons edit toolbar]

The logo goes wonky at 110% zoom:

[image]

I don't know enough about SVG and CSS to diagnose why. They've got a fuzzy look that almost resembles motion-blur to me.

Note: the issue isn't *quite* as bad as the imgur-compressed image shows.

I double-checked the emulation settings I had on, and they are the default (Document mode = Edge, Browser profile = Desktop, User agent string = Default). I also do not have Compatibility view enabled.